# Spring Boot embedded jar and application.properties location

Tags: spring-boot

I thought I had this working because in my IDE the correct environment properties file was being used, and a local application.properties was being correctly used. I am trying to use [profile specific properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) to determine various values throughout my Spring-Boot 1.3.5 app.

[image]

My src/main/resources/application.properties is:

```
spring.profiles.active=test
server.port=8080
deploy.server=http://localhost
liquibase.change-log:classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
liquibase.check-change-log-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
logging.file=myapp.log
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

And I have a src/main/resources/application-test.properties:

```
server.port=8081
deploy.server=https://test.myapp.com
logging.level.liquibase:TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.security:DEBUG
```

Now I apparently have two problems:

1. After I run "gradle clean build" I get my jar and trying to run via:

> java -jar build/libs/app.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local

I see the message:

> The following profiles are active: test

So it picking that up from the application.properties file and I can't seem to override it, which I think is causing my second problem:

2. My Jenkins build fails when I try to use a parameterized build with the values:
   spring.profiles.active set to "test".
   [image]
   The error I get is Tomcat in a failed state.  If I take that parameter out of the build, it works.  But that build will not run from the command line unless I copy the application-{env}.properties to the run directory (which might be best practice anyway?).

I am not sure if the problem is the location of the properties files or the way I am trying to build them.

Comment: It works for me, but one small test, can you remove the property from `application.properties` and check things work as you expected?

Comment: do you mean remove a property from the application.properties file that doesn't exist in one of the other application-{env}.properties file?